# How to load data with new self construction php

Tags: php, static-methods

I can not load data to properties using this construction I receive null in dump

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Good;


        class GoodDto
        {

            public $name;
            public $articul;
            public $price;
            public $type;
            public $qnt;
            public $discount;
            public $category;
            public $description;
            public $description2;
            public $color;


            public function load($data)
            {
                $this->name = $data['name'];
                $this->articul = $data['artikul'];
                $this->price = $data['price'];
                $this->type = (isset($data['type'])) ? $data['type'] : null;
                $this->qnt = $data['count'];
                $this->discount = $data['spinner-decimal'];
                $this->category = $data['id_cat'];
                $this->description = $data['editor1'];
                $this->description2 = '';
                $this->color = $data['color'];
                //$this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            }

            public static function fromRequest($request)
            {
                dump('inp=>',(new self ())->load($request->input()));
                return (new self ())->load($request->input());

            }
        }
```

Please explain to me why I receive null while request->input() is an array, I call it from another place

```
$dto=GoodDto::fromRequest($request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Method chaining, returns the last return from the chain. The other returns are used to call the next link in the chain.

```
(new self ())->load()
```

So `load()` needs to return `$this`

```
 public function load($data)
 {
      ...
     return $this; 
 }
```

Currently it returns `null`, which is why it returns null.

See you are not saving the instance from the constructor, instead you pass it to load by enclosing it within the `(....)`.  By pass it I mean you call the load method on the return from the constructor.

You can test this like so:

```
class foo{

    function load(){
        return $this;//return this
    }
}

var_dump((new foo)->load());

class bar{

    function load(){
       //return null
    }
}

var_dump((new bar)->load());
```

Output

```
 //return this
object(foo)#1 (0) {
}
//return null
NULL
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9760da613b1c83851edc07e20f56654e6c2f733e)

The second class in the example above `class bar`, is essentially what you are doing.

PS. forgot to scroll down on your post at first ... lol ... So I had to update my answer.

**Bonus**

You can also simplify the load code like this:

```
   public function load($data)
   {
      foreach($data as $prop=>$value){
          if(property_exists($this,$prop)) $this->$prop = $value;
      }
      return $this;
   }
```

This way if you add new properties you don't have to edit the load method ever again, you just have to name the array elements the same as the class properties.  You can even throw an error if the property does not exist if you want, by adding an `else` to the condition etc...

Personally, when I do this I prefer to call a set method like this:

```
   //eg. $data = ['foo' => '2019-06-16']
   public function load(array $data)
   {
      foreach($data as $prop=>$value){
          $method = 'set'.$prop;  //$method = 'setfoo' using the example above
          if(method_exists($this,$method )){
              $this->$method($value); //calls 'setfoo' with '2019-06-16'
          }else{
              throw new Exception('Unknown method '.$method);
          }
      }
      return $this;
   }

   public function setFoo($date){
       $this->foo = new DateTime($date);
   }
```

Then you can apply some transforms to the data etc...  PHP method names are not case sensitive.  You can even combine these by first checking for a method then a property then throw the error etc...

Cheers.